# Prove determinants of matrices are equal using row elementary operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Verify that the determinants of the following two matrices are equal to each other using only elementary row operations and without expanding the determinants.

\begin{bmatrix}a-b&1&a\\b-c&1&b\\c-a&1&c\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}a&1&b\\b&1&c\\c&1&a\end{bmatrix}

I attempted to solve this problem by using row swaps for both matrices such that the last column of each matrix is equal to each other. After that, I'm stuck and not exactly sure of how to continue.

Comment: Are you allowed to transpose the matrix first?

Comment: @Bungo Yes, we are allowed to transpose the matrix

Comment: Starting with the first matrix, subtract the first column from the third column, then add the new third column to the first column. The result is the second matrix. You can convert these to row operations by transposing the matrix first.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{bmatrix}a-b&1&a\\b-c&1&b\\c-a&1&c\end{bmatrix} $$

$R_1\rightarrow R_1 + (a+b+c)R_2$

---

$$\begin{bmatrix}2a+c&1&a\\2b+c&1&b\\2c+a&1&c\end{bmatrix}$$

$R_1\rightarrow R_1 -2R_3$

---

$$\begin{bmatrix}c&1&a\\a&1&b\\b&1&c\end{bmatrix}$$

And now changing 2 rows give desired result.